# Error due to matrices dimensions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have to implement the below mentioned code by using two matrices which sizes are 273839x2  and 17642065x2 in order to find out distance between all pairs stored in matrixA and all pairs stored in matrixB:

```
d=2;
numA = 17642065;
numB = 273839;
helpA = zeros(numA,3*d);
helpB = zeros(numB,3*d);
for idx = 1:d
helpA(:,3*idx-2:3*idx) = [ones(numA,1), -2*A(:,idx), A(:,idx).^2 ];
helpB(:,3*idx-2:3*idx) = [B(:,idx).^2 ,    B(:,idx), ones(numB,1)];
end
distMat = helpA * helpB'
```

but on the execution of code MATLAB gives following error " Error using horzcat .CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent". kindly give me suggestions how to remove this error. thanks

Comment: What is `A` and `B`?

Comment: A and B are both are matrices. Size of matrix A is 17642065x2 and size of matrix B is 273839x2. Pixel values are stored in both matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Well, please let us know what A and B are.

What are you concatenating?

If you are doing `Mat_AB = horzcat(A,B)`; it is clear from the MATLAB documentation and the error you are getting that the number of rows (in `A` and `B`) have to be same to concatenate matrices horizontally.  Check if this is true.

Note that if you execute: `Mat_AB = vertcat(A,B)` then the number of columns in `A` and `B` have to be same.

Comment: A and B are both are matrices. Size of matrix A is 17642065x2 and size of matrix B is 273839x2. Pixel values are stored in both matrices.